# How to concatenate two numpy ndarrays without using concatenate

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am writing code which utilizes Numba to JIT compile my python code.
The function takes in two arrays of same length as input, randomly selects a slicing point and returns a tuple with two Frankenstein array formed by parts of the two input strings.
Numba however does not yet support the numpy.concatenate function (don't know if it ever will). As I am unwilling to drop Numpy, does anyone know a performant solution for concatenating two Numpy arrays without the concatenate function?

```
def randomSlice(str1, str2):
    lenstr = len(str1)
    rnd = np.random.randint(1, lenstr)
    return (np.concatenate((str1[:rnd], str2[rnd:])), np.concatenate((str2[:rnd], str1[rnd:])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def randomSlice_nb(str1, str2):
    lenstr = len(str1)
    rnd = np.random.randint(1, lenstr)

    out1 = np.empty_like(str1)
    out2 = np.empty_like(str1)

    out1[:rnd] = str1[:rnd]
    out1[rnd:] = str2[rnd:]

    out2[:rnd] = str2[:rnd]
    out2[rnd:] = str1[rnd:]
    return (out1, out2)
```

On my machine, using Numba 0.27 and timing via the `timeit` module to make sure I'm not counting the jit time in the stats (or you could run it once, and then time subsequent calls), the numba version gives a small but non-negligible performance increase on various size input arrays of ints or floats. If the arrays have a dtype of something like `|S1`, then numba is significantly slower. The Numba team has spent very little time optimizing non-numeric usecases so this isn't terribly surprising. I'm a little unclear about the exact form of your input arrays `str1` and `str2`, so I can't exactly guarantee that the code will work for your specific usecase.

Comment: Works like a charm. I am just wondering about the performance overhead incurred due to replacing elements on out1 and out2, but for now that is exactally what I needed. Thanks a lot bud. (for the record the str inputs were just plain 1D ndarrays)

Comment: When you use `np.empty` or `np.empty_like`, you're just allocating memory for the array and not filling it, so it should be fast. Most numpy functions that return a new array have to do something similar, albeit often using a lower-level C function like `PyArray_ConcatenateArrays`. Even then you can see that function allocates memory and then copies data into it.

Comment: The only way you can get around this is if you pre-allocate output arrays and pass them in, which is something I will do occasionally if I'm going to be creating lots of small arrays over and over again. It makes the code uglier though.