# Numpy's hstack troubles with Numba

Tags: numpy, numba

I am having trouble compiling a simple function in no-Python mode with Numba:

```py
@njit 
def fun(x,y):
   points = np.hstack((x,y))
   return points

a = 5
b = 2
res = fun(a,b)
```

While this very simple script works without the `@njit` decorator, if run with it throws the error:

```py
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function hstack at 0x7f491475fe50>) found for signature:
 
 >>> hstack(UniTuple(int64 x 2))
 
There are 4 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 4 did not match due to:
      Overload in function '_OverloadWrapper._build.<locals>.ol_generated': File: numba/core/overload_glue.py: Line 129.
        With argument(s): '(UniTuple(int64 x 2))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypeError: np.hstack(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays, got UniTuple(int64 x 2)
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numba/core/typing/npydecl.py:748

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function hstack at 0x7f491475fe50>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-41-7a0a3bcd4b1a> (28)


File "<ipython-input-41-7a0a3bcd4b1a>", line 28:
def fun(x, y):
  points = np.hstack((x, y))
  ^
```

If I try to stack one scalar and one array (which it might be the case in the original function from which this problem arised), the behavior doesn't change:

```py
b = np.ones(3)
res = fun(a,b)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function hstack at 0x7f491475fe50>) found for signature:
 
 >>> hstack(Tuple(int64, array(float64, 1d, C)))
 
There are 4 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 4 did not match due to:
      Overload in function '_OverloadWrapper._build.<locals>.ol_generated': File: numba/core/overload_glue.py: Line 129.
        With argument(s): '(Tuple(int64, array(float64, 1d, C)))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypeError: np.hstack(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays, got Tuple(int64, array(float64, 1d, C))
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numba/core/typing/npydecl.py:748

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function hstack at 0x7f491475fe50>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-42-39bffd13df71> (28)


File "<ipython-input-42-39bffd13df71>", line 28:
def fun(x, y):
  points = np.hstack((x, y))
```

This is very puzzling to me. I am using Numba 0.56.4—which should be the last stable release.

A very similar behavior happens with `np.concatenate`, too.
Any suggestion would much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two numpy ndarrays without using concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705094/how-to-concatenate-two-numpy-ndarrays-without-using-concatenate). Besides, in your case, it does not make sense to concatenate integers. This is why Numba refuses to do that. You need to build an array instead of trying to concatenate numbers.

Comment: The numpy `hstack` makes sure the inputs are at least 1d arrays and then uses `concatenate`. I wouldn't be surprised if the `numba` version expects the inputs to already be arrays. Loosing some flexibility on inputs is a normal cost of moving to faster compiled code.

Comment: Actually, converting the input in np.array does make the code work. It seems this is a viable solution. Thank you very much.